# Modal will not fade away after calling .modal('hide')

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

First time working with modal's and my fade is not working correctly, it will disappear upon cancelling, but will not disappear after confirming a delete.

Here is my modal w/ button

```
<span class="item-delete-button">
       <button class="btn btn-danger col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.ID" onclick="deleteStart(this)">
            <span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete
        </button>
            </span>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="@item.ID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                      <span style="font-size: 20px">Are you sure you want to delete Employee: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)?</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" onclick="deleteStopped(this)" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                      <button type="button" onclick="deleteFunction(this)" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm Delete</button>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Here is all my JQuery

```
function deleteStart(element) {
        $(element).closest("table").toggleClass("table-hover");
        $(element).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'red');
    }

    function deleteStopped(element) {
        $(element).closest("table").toggleClass("table-hover");
        $(element).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'initial');
    }

    function deleteFunction(element) {
        var newID = $(element).closest("td").find("span.ID").text();

                $.post(
            '@Url.Action("customDelete", "Employee")',
            {
                'id': newID
            },
            function (data) { },
            "json"
            );
                $(element).closest("tr").next("tr").remove();
                $(element).closest("tr").remove();             

                $(element).closest("table").toggleClass("table-hover");
                $(element).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'initial');
                $('.modal').modal('hide');     
    }
```

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: I tried adding `$('.modal').modal('hide');` but that does not seem to be helping, am I reference it incorrectly?

Comment: `$('.modal').modal('hide')`?

Comment: For some reason that isn't doing it...thus why I am confused haha, I added this to the very end of my deleteFunction, right after the `.css('background-`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue found!

If you try to `hide` the modal within a function that temporarily leaves the View (such as AJAX) then you must end your modal's scripts before then or else they get lost in the application, and thus you cannot `hide` it.

To do this you must immediately call the following within your function before any other functions/methods are called such an AJAX Post in my situation.

This gets rid of the `fade` and then `hides` it.

```
$('#myModal').removeClass('fade');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't hide your modal after performing the delete.

At the bottom part of your deleteFunction() add a $('.modal').modal('hide'); this will close your modal manually.

See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: For some reason that isn't doing it...thus why I am confused haha, I added this to the very end of my deleteFunction, right after the `.css('background-`....

Comment: Try moving the code inside the function(data) of your $.post, since it will be executed after it receives a response.

Comment: The issue was with the `fade` class. Thank you for the help!